# How to replace value for a given condition in specific column of file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, replace, text-formatting

I have file separetd by pipe `|` and I want that when column 6 contain letter `I` print `0758000` in column 7 and
when the column 6 contain letter `A` print `0800000` in column 7, I can not find how to do it!!!

Example:

Original file

```
cat file1.txt
Z89|EEE333333|100001|JANMC84|19990101|I|1800040
Z89|EEE444444|200001|JANMC84|19990101|I|1800040
Z89|EEE222222|300001|JANMC84|19990101|A|1800040
Z89|EEE555555|700001|JANMC84|19990101|A|1800040
```

The result should be:

```
Z89|EEE333333|100001|JANMC84|19990101|I|0758000
Z89|EEE444444|200001|JANMC84|19990101|I|0758000
Z89|EEE222222|300001|JANMC84|19990101|A|0800000
Z89|EEE555555|700001|JANMC84|19990101|A|0800000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with awk like

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} $6 == "A" {$7 = "0800000"} $6 == "I" {$7 = "0758000"}; 1' file1.txt
```

This will have `awk` split fields based on `|`, then set the output field separator to also be `|` when we write the lines back out.  Then if the sixth field, `$6`, is `A` replace the seventh field with a particular value, and a different value if it's an I.  Then print the line out at the end, with our changes if we made any.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\(I|\)[^|]*$/\10758000/;s/\(A|\)[^|]*$/\10800000/' file1.txt
```

The point is to `s`ubstitute everything that comes after `I|` or `A|` (i.e. last column) with desired numbers.

Result:

```
Z89|EEE333333|100001|JANMC84|19990101|I|0758000
Z89|EEE444444|200001|JANMC84|19990101|I|0758000
Z89|EEE222222|300001|JANMC84|19990101|A|0800000
Z89|EEE555555|700001|JANMC84|19990101|A|0800000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SLPJP_Box                                                        11/03/2017 22:00:07  -----                RU 13232789/1
 SLPJP_PRD_SOB_MAIN                                              09/07/2017 22:00:30  09/07/2017 22:00:57  OI 11769239/1 0
 SLPJP_PRD_SOD_BOX                                               11/03/2017 22:00:18  -----                RU 13232789/1
  SLPJP_PRD_SOD_001                                              11/03/2017 22:00:34  11/03/2017 23:10:25  SU 13232789/1 0
  SLPJP_PRD_SOD_002                                              11/03/2017 23:10:26  -----                RU 13232789/1
  SLPJP_PRD_SOD_003                                              -----                11/02/2017 22:18:34  AC 13232789/0
  SLPJP_PRD_SOD_004                                              -----                11/02/2017 22:19:55  AC 13232789/0
```

I want to print all column but remove all column SU, OI, AC  column and remove all blank sapce to any seperator